# Is there any danger in removing '.' components from a path?

Tags: path, symbolic-link

**Can the transformation of a path `A/./B` into `A/B` change the meaning of the path?**

I am aware that the path `A/foo/../B` may not refer to the same object as `A/B`, due to symbolic links (if `foo` is a symlink, then `A/foo/..` may not be the same object as `A`). I would like to check that there are no similar dangers with `A/./B`

Comment: I would think that `readlink -f /any/path/with/or/without/symlinks` always works best.

Comment: @StefanSeidel: The question is about safe manipulation of paths as strings (i.e., without accessing the file-system).

Comment: By definition, `.` always refers to the current directory. It comes in handy occasionally in specific circumstances, but is usually redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In theory*, `.` is not ***guaranteed*** to be the current directory, just as `..` is not ***guaranteed*** to be the parent directory.  However, if they aren’t, you have either filesystem corruption (in which case all bets are off) or very high wizardry, which you are not likely to encounter in real life.  I’d say it’s safe to remove the ‘**.**’ components.

Comment: What kind of wizardry would affect the `. == current` directory? I know how symlinks can affect `..` but I would have thought `.` to be quite robust. Could you please post a link?

Comment: In Windows, I believe `.` and `..` are pseudo-entries that `DIR` displays and `CD` (and other pathname resolution services) honor.   In Unix, they are actual entries in the directory.  If you say `rm foo`, `rm` checks whether `foo` is a directory and refuses to continue if it is (unless you have specified `-r`).  You could write a version of `rm` that didn't do that test.  Then, if you were root, you could `rm .` and `ln /some/other/directory .`.  Or at least it worked that way years ago; it may have changed; I haven't tried it recently.  Warning: This is more dangerous than `regedit`!

Comment: @terdon: Oh, also, a privileged user could run a hex editor on an unmounted file system disk; e.g., `db /dev/hda2`.